# Android Re-scaling X Axis when zooming in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there any way to be able to re-scale the X-axis as you zoom in?

For instance, the initial X-axis scale is by day and as you zoom in to a certain day X-axis scale becomes by hour.

Like my scenario is to scale X-axis with dates (i.e. Jul 5, Jul 6, Jul 7...) and after zooming in on a certain level I want to see the hours (i.e. 10:00, 11:00, 12:00...) on my X-axis to have a more accurate information about my data item.

Thanks.

Comment: The only one way at the moment as i see is to rewrite your own renderers and handle scale factor to show time instead of date, also set X values as millis

Comment: check [this page](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/120).  and [this onme](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).